# Is there a way to log specific clicks?

Tags: 2013, javascript, reporting-services, logging, reports

I need to log when users click on specific links on our SharePoint site. Something like:

> bob@company.com - Clicked Special Link #1 - 02/13/2015 14:41
>
> joe@company.com - Clicked Special Link #7 - 02/13/2015 14:41

I can intercept the clicks with JavaScript if needed.

Any suggestions on how this can be done? Is there something built into SharePoint that I'm overlooking?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the REST/JSOM API to log your own usage to show up in SharePoint usage analytics. For example the REST endpoint looks like this:
"/_api/Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPAnalyticsUsageService/logevent"

You can look at the full code example on doing this from JavaScript here:
http://sharepointfieldnotes.blogspot.com/2013/11/more-sharepoint-2013-rest-code-tips.html

Comment: This looks good but it's not working for me. When I set EventTypeId to 0, I get back "Invalid parameter: EventTypeId."

Comment: There is no documentation on the eventTypeId. It looks like the "custom" is limited to between 512 and 518. Try that.

Comment: The data object I get back has a property called logevent, but it's value is null. Where do you see the logs for custom events in SharePoint?

Comment: The logevent always returns null.This may not meet your needs. You can only see the usage events using the "popularity trends" reports for sites, lists and listitems. The site usage can be generated from the "Popularity and Search Reports" in site settings. These will not show custom events. The only place custom events will show are on listitems. You select a listitem in a list, then select "Poulartity Trends" ribbon button after selecting the Files tab. You may be able to achieve this if your pages are contained in a document library like site pages.